# In Itext 7 find width of string requiring multiple fonts

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext7

Using iText 7 (7.0.2), how does one find the width of a string that contains characters that require different fonts?

For example, in the code below, there are both English and Russian characters.   I would like to find the width of that string based on the fonts assigned to each character by a FontProvider.

```
String s = "Hello world! Здравствуй мир! Hello world! Здравствуй мир!";
FontProvider sel = new FontProvider();
sel.addFont(fontsFolder + "NotoSans-Regular.ttf");
sel.addFont(fontsFolder + "Puritan2.otf");
```

If the string only had characters that can be rendered with one font, I could do this:

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontsFolder + "Puritan2.otf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
font.getWidth(s, 12f);
```

Given that there is not a getWidth method on the FontProvider itself, I'll need to iterate through the pieces of the string and add up the length of each based on the font used. Looking for an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a very low level you indeed have to iterate over the pieces of the original string decomposed according to the font being used for each piece.

The code would look like this:

```
// Get the strategy that is responsible for splitting. 
// The "FreeSans" argument is the "preferred" font.
FontSelectorStrategy strategy = sel.getStrategy(s, Arrays.asList("FreeSans"));
float totalWidth = 0;
while (!strategy.endOfText()) {
    for (Glyph glyph : strategy.nextGlyphs()) {
        totalWidth += glyph.getWidth();
    }
}
// Division by font unit size, because glyph.getWidth() is a 1000-based value
totalWidth /= 1000;
// Multiplication by font size
totalWidth *= 12;
```

Comment: Thanks!  Simplier than I was thinking.  Appreciate the explanation of 1000-based width and font size also.

Comment: How does one know the preferred font?

Comment: @JoeEltgroth, if you don't know the preferred font, you can pass any string, even empty string. The preferred font is something like specifying font-family in HTML. Another font will be used in case the "preferred" font cannot render the desired glyphs anyway. But if, say, you have "Arial" and "Times New Roman" in your font provider and you set "Arial" as preferred font, Arial will have higher priority all else being equal